# iOS: Footer jumps to middle of page when clicking input box

Tags: ios, uiwebview, footer, landscape

I have a uiwebview for some reason, if I click in a box to enter, say a username. The footer jumps above to the middle of the screen and you can't see what you are typing.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? This issue only occurs when I'm in landscape mode. Portrait mode works fine.

I'm testing on iPhone6 device.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I was able to fix this issue was by removing the footer image via Javascript.

Example:

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"var element = document.getElementById('%@'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);", @"tagIDName", nil];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```